# How to get more information about the changes returned by scm list changes?

Tags: rational-team-concert

I am using the RTC scm command to compile a list of files changed in a specified work item.  For the sake of clarity, let's assume I've already logged in and created the nickname rtc for my RTC repository connection.  I can use

```
scm list changesets -r rtc -W 222333
```

to get the changeset aliases for the workitem.  I can use, given that alias 1001 is returned for the one changeset associated with work item 222333.

```
scm list changes 1001
```

to list the changes associated with each of the changeset aliases returned by scm list changesets.  Here is an example output I get:

```
Change sets:
  (1001) ----@ John L. Czukkermann "Add the common headers filter to the project WARs."
    Component: (1002) "projecta"
    Modified: 30-Aug-2018 07:35 AM
    Changes:
      ---c- (1003) /<unresolved>/web.xml
      ---c- (1004) /<unresolved>/web.xml
    Work items:
      (1005) 270248 "Add filters to web.xml for WAR a"
      (1000) 270247 "Add filters to web.xml for WAR b"
```

What I don't seem to be able to do is to get the detailed information related to aliases 1003 and 1004; specifically, I want to know the path associated with the file.